# How to generate Kubelet config file for kubernetes v1.14.0

Tags: kubernetes, systemd, kubelet

I just upgraded my local k8s cluster (v1.3.0) to 1.14.0 which i built from scratch, After upgrade kublet service is not starting (systemd unit ) , error message is saying some options are deprecated and need to use new config file method, But i couldn't find any documentation for it , How can I convert my existing kubelet parameters to new config file method (--config flag) ?

Existing kubelet config (systemd service)

```
/usr/bin/kubelet --allow-privileged=true \
  --api-servers=https://10.240.0.21:6443,https://10.240.0.22:6443 \
  --cloud-provider= --cluster-dns=10.32.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
  --configure-cbr0=true --non-masquerade-cidr=10.32.0.0/24 \
  --container-runtime=docker --docker=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
  --network-plugin=kubenet --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
  --reconcile-cidr=true --serialize-image-pulls=false \
  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \
  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem --v=2
```

Comment: *But i couldn't find any documentation for it* you will appreciate if I find that statement [oppressively false](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/) -- or rather, I hear you that you *didn't bother* but I don't believe that you *couldn't*

Answer (score 0):

I found the following two commands to be helpful in my quest to create a kubelet configuration file:

```
sudo kubeadm config print init-defaults --component-configs KubeletConfiguration
sudo kubeadm config print join-defaults --component-configs KubeletConfiguration
```

the first command for example will give you the following defaults for a kubelet config yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
clusterDNS:
- 10.96.0.10
clusterDomain: cluster.local
cpuManagerReconcilePeriod: 0s
evictionPressureTransitionPeriod: 0s
fileCheckFrequency: 0s
healthzBindAddress: 127.0.0.1
healthzPort: 10248
httpCheckFrequency: 0s
imageMinimumGCAge: 0s
kind: KubeletConfiguration
nodeStatusReportFrequency: 0s
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: 0s
rotateCertificates: true
runtimeRequestTimeout: 0s
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
streamingConnectionIdleTimeout: 0s
syncFrequency: 0s
volumeStatsAggPeriod: 0s
```

To generate an existing kubelet configuration on a host ssh to that host and execute:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8001 &
 [1] 22461
$ Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Change NODE_NAME var to your hostname and execute

```
NODE_NAME="k8s-node2"; curl -sSL "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/${NODE_NAME}/proxy/configz" | jq '.kubeletconfig|.kind="KubeletConfiguration"|.apiVersion="kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"' > kubelet_config_${NODE_NAME}
```

you will now have a file that looks resembles this:

```
cat kubelet_config_hostname
{
  "staticPodPath": "/etc/kubernetes/manifests",
  "syncFrequency": "1m0s",
  "fileCheckFrequency": "20s",
  "httpCheckFrequency": "20s",
  "address": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 10250,
  "tlsCertFile": "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt",
  "tlsPrivateKeyFile": "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key",
  "rotateCertificates": true,
  "authentication": {
    "x509": {
      "clientCAFile": "/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
    },
    "webhook": {
      "enabled": true,
      "cacheTTL": "2m0s"
    },
    "anonymous": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "mode": "Webhook",
    "webhook": {
      "cacheAuthorizedTTL": "5m0s",
      "cacheUnauthorizedTTL": "30s"
    }
  },
  "registryPullQPS": 5,
  "registryBurst": 10,
  "eventRecordQPS": 5,
  "eventBurst": 10,
  "enableDebuggingHandlers": true,
  "healthzPort": 10248,
  "healthzBindAddress": "127.0.0.1",
  "oomScoreAdj": -999,
  "clusterDomain": "cluster.local",
  "clusterDNS": [
    "10.96.0.10"
  ],
  "streamingConnectionIdleTimeout": "4h0m0s",
  "nodeStatusUpdateFrequency": "10s",
  "nodeStatusReportFrequency": "5m0s",
  "nodeLeaseDurationSeconds": 40,
  "imageMinimumGCAge": "2m0s",
  "imageGCHighThresholdPercent": 85,
  "imageGCLowThresholdPercent": 80,
  "volumeStatsAggPeriod": "1m0s",
  "cgroupsPerQOS": true,
  "cgroupDriver": "systemd",
  "cpuManagerPolicy": "none",
  "cpuManagerReconcilePeriod": "10s",
  "topologyManagerPolicy": "none",
  "runtimeRequestTimeout": "2m0s",
  "hairpinMode": "promiscuous-bridge",
  "maxPods": 110,
  "podPidsLimit": -1,
  "resolvConf": "/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf",
  "cpuCFSQuota": true,
  "cpuCFSQuotaPeriod": "100ms",
  "maxOpenFiles": 1000000,
  "contentType": "application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf",
  "kubeAPIQPS": 5,
  "kubeAPIBurst": 10,
  "serializeImagePulls": true,
  "evictionHard": {
    "imagefs.available": "15%",
    "memory.available": "100Mi",
    "nodefs.available": "10%",
    "nodefs.inodesFree": "5%"
  },
  "evictionPressureTransitionPeriod": "5m0s",
  "enableControllerAttachDetach": true,
  "makeIPTablesUtilChains": true,
  "iptablesMasqueradeBit": 14,
  "iptablesDropBit": 15,
  "failSwapOn": true,
  "containerLogMaxSize": "10Mi",
  "containerLogMaxFiles": 5,
  "configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy": "Watch",
  "enforceNodeAllocatable": [
    "pods"
  ],
  "kind": "KubeletConfiguration",
  "apiVersion": "kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"
}
```